# Position of icon in QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt

My `QTreeWidget` has a single column. Its items have a check box, an icon, and text. If the user clicks inside an item, I want to know whether the icon was clicked. How can I find the position and size of the icon in a `QTreeWidgetItem`?

**Updated to add:** Here is the code for my eventual solution, as requested by webclectic.

First, I sub-classed `QItemDelegate` so that I could access the coordinates of each part of a `QTreeWidgetItem` (check box, icon, and text). Here is the header file:

```
#include <QItemDelegate>

class MyItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
  {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MyItemDelegate (MyTreeWidget *parent)
    : QItemDelegate (parent), ParentView (parent) { }
  ~MyItemDelegate() { }

  void GetRects (const QModelIndex &index, QRect& CheckBox, QRect& Icon, QRect& Text) const ;

private:
  MyTreeWidget* ParentView ;
  } ;
```

And here is the source file:

```
void MyItemDelegate::GetRects (const QModelIndex &index, QRect& CheckBox, QRect& Icon, QRect& Text) const
  {
  QStyleOptionViewItem option = ParentView -> viewOptions() ;
  CheckBox = rect (option, index, Qt::CheckStateRole) ;
  Icon = rect (option, index, Qt::DecorationRole) ;
  Text = rect (option, index, Qt::DisplayRole) ;

  doLayout (option, &CheckBox, &Icon, &Text, true) ;

  QRect VisualRect = ParentView -> visualRect (index) ;
  CheckBox.translate (VisualRect.topLeft()) ;
  Icon.translate (VisualRect.topLeft()) ;
  Text.translate (VisualRect.topLeft()) ;
  }
```

Then I added a `MyItemDelegate*` member to `MyTreeWidget`, and set it as the item view's delegate. In the header:

```
class MyTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
  {
  ...
  MyItemDelegate* Delegate ;
  ...
  } ;
```

In the source :

```
MyTreeWidget::MyTreeWidget (QObject* parent)
  {
  ...
  Delegate = new MyItemDelegate (this) ;
  setItemDelegate (ItemDelegate) ;
  }
```

Now, to get the coordinates of each part of a `QTreeWidgetItem`:

```
  QTreeWidgetItem* item ;
  ...
  QModelIndex ModelIndex = indexFromItem (item) ;
  QRect CheckBoxRect, IconRect, TextRect ;
  ItemDelegate -> GetRects (ModelIndex, &CheckBoxRect, &IconRect, &TextRect) ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple way to achieve what you want. The problem is that `QTreeWidget` is responsible for painting its items so the item itself has no information about the position of its elements in the view.

First of all you have to subclass `QTreeWidget` and reimplement the `mousePressEvent` (or `mouseReleaseEvent` if you prefer). Inside the event you should calculate the position of the icon and handle it correspondingly.

Sample code (but untested) follows:

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   QModelIndex clickedIndex = indexAt(event->pos());
   // make sure the event was on a valid item
   if (clickedIndex.isValid() == false)
      return;

   // Get the tree widget's x position
   int treeX = header()->sectionViewportPosition(0);

   // Get the x coordinate of the root item. It is required in order to calculate
   // the identation of the item
   int rootX = visualRect(rootIndex()).x();

   // Get the rectangle of the viewport occupied by the pressed item
   QRect vrect = visualRect(clickedIndex);

   // Now we can easily calculate the x coordinate of the item
   int itemX = treeX + vrect.x() - rootX; 

   // The item is a checkbox, then an icon and finally the text. 

   // 1. Get the rect surrounding the checkbox
   QRect checkboxRect = QRect(itemX, 
                              vrect.y(), 
                              style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_IndicatorWidth),
                              vrect.height()); 

   // 2. Get the rect surrounding the icon
   QRect iconRect = QRect(itemX + checkboxRect.width(),
                          vrect.y(),
                          iconSize().width(),
                          vrect.height());

   // 3. Finally get the rect surrounding the text
   QRect textRect = QRect(itemX + checkboxRect.width() + iconRect.width(),
                          vrect.y(),
                          vrect.width() - checkboxRect.width() - iconRect.width(),
                          vrect.height());       

   // Now check where the press event took place and handle it correspondingly

   if(checkboxRect.contains(event->pos())) 
   {
       qDebug() << "Checkbox pressed";
       QTreeWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
       return;
   } 
   else if (iconRect.contains(event->pos()))
   {
       qDebug() << "Icon pressed";
       QTreeWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
       return;
   }
   else
   {
       qDebug() << "Text pressed";
       QTreeWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
       return; 
   }
}
```

I repeat that the code is untested but you get the idea about how to achieve what you want.

Comment: I tried this out, and that thing with `PM_IndicatorWidth` works just fine. Thanks for that! Also, `iconSize()` returns (-1,-1), but if I call `setIconSize()` first it works. That looks circular, but in fact it solved my problem with the icons being smaller than I wanted.

Comment: After some testing, I discovered that this solution doesn't work either -- it ignores the margins around the check box and the icon. To do it properly, I had to sub-class QItemDelegate and provide a version of sizeHint that returns the three parts (check box, icon, text) separately. But you set me on the right track.

Comment: Could you post some working code, as edit in your question, for future reference?

Comment: Done. Well, not working code, exactly -- I had to prune out too much.

Comment: @TonyK Looking at the source code for QItemDelegate, you an get the margin with `style()->pixelMetric( QStyle::PM_FocusFrameHMargin ) + 1`. The magic +1 is not very self-explanatory though, but it works relatively well although +2 seems to work even better for some reason I don't understand but that's hair splitting.