# Qt - Centering Icon in QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt

Trying to center an icon within a QTreeWidgetItem. The formatting set with setTextAlignment() only applies to text within the column. For example:

```
item = new QTreeWidgetItem(tree);

item->setIcon(0, QIcon(QPixMap(imageFile));
item->setTextAlignment(0, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);

tree->addTopLevelItem(item);
```

This will create a column with a left-aligned icon (and text center-aligned if there is any). Is there a way to center-align the icon with a custom stylesheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no simple solution to change the position of an icon within a QTreeWidgetItem.

As a workaround, you can maybe use [setItemWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget) and set as widget an instance of QLabel containing a well centered pixmap.

Another solution derivated from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274944/1887976) could work, but is not trivial. If you create a new class child of QTreeWidgetItem and tweak the painting actions, you will maybe be able to draw the icon where you want. Very painfull in my opinion.